# How are output files handled in Hadoop at job and task level ?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

AS per The Definitive Guide, setUpJob() of OutPutCommitter will create the mapreduce output directory and also setup the temporary workspace for tasks.  mapred.output.dir/_temporary

Then the book says temporary directories at task level are created when task outputs are written.

The above two statements are kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

So basically a map reduce job consist of many task i.e map tasks and reduce tasks. Now mapreduce output directory is the directory where the final output of map-reduce job is written. Now when the map reduce job runs each of the map task and reduce tasks generate intermediate files which is local to the node where the task run. This local output per task  which are intermediate are written to  temporary workspace. Finally after shuffling and other phases this intermediate outputs are finally written to hdfs as final output based on the logic you apply for the map-reduce job. I hope that answers your question